# Binding SQLite with ListView : How to display rows numbered 1,2,3,4,5?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have this table:

```
ROW_ID ROW_USER_NAME ROW_SCORE
```

And I want to display top five scores from this table. I am extending CursorAdapter and overriding it's methods. Everything is working fine except I want to replace ROW_ID with numbers `1,2,3,4,5`.  How can I do that?

Comment: This is not an easy thing to do in SQLite, as it has no native support for a row number analytic function.  But other than the row number, the query itself is not hard, and you could add ranks in your view layer.

Comment: how can I do that. Please give me example. I'm beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a) that the rows are sorted according to the sequence and b) that you just want to display the numbers and not store them then simply set the respective View to the position.

If you do this in the overridden `getView` method then position is passed to `getView` as the first parameter (int). So it's simply a matter of using something like :-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertview, parent);

    TextView sequence = view.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
    sequence.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    .......
}
```

You could alternately do this in the overridden `bindView` method. However the position isn't passed rather the Cursor is passed as the 3rd parameter, so you would get the Cursor's position, using something like :-

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {
    TextView sequence = view.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
    sequence.setText(String.valueOf(csr.getPosition()) + 1);
    .......
}
```